# Youtube iFrame API 'YT is undefined'

Tags: javascript, iframe, module, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm trying to put this code in an module function:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        VIDEO.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();
}


        var VIDEO = (function (my, $){
var tag = document.createElement('script');
var onPlayerStateChange;
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;


   my.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady =function() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '490',
      width: '880',
      videoId: SONG.getArtistId(),
      playerVars: { controls:1, showinfo: 0, rel: 0, showsearch: 0, iv_load_policy: 3 },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
        'onError': catchError
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {


  if(typeof(SONG.getArtistId()) == undefined)
  {
    console.log("undefineeeed"); 
  } 


    event.target.playVideo();   
  }

  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      // setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
    if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED)
    {
      location.reload();
    }
  }

  function catchError(event)
  {
    if(event.data == 100) console.log("De video bestaat niet meer");
  }

  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }

  return my;

}(VIDEO || {}, jQuery));
```

The problem is: even it's self-executing, nothing happens and the iFrame is not shown.
I'm trying to do this because it's part of an assignment. We have to work in modules.

Comment: 1. you didn't hook up the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function to any event. 2. `var VIDEO` is declared outside of the `script` tag 3. you are using Jquery without referencing it on your page.

Comment: @avrahamcool I'm sorry, I pasted the wrong code. I edited my post. (I have a reference to use jQuery, that's not the problem)

I get: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: YT is not defined'

Comment: create a fiddle that demonstrate the problem, it will be easier to help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to simplify the code :

**HTML**

```
<div id="player"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  console.log( "ready!" );
  loadPlayer();
});

function getArtistId() {
  return 'l-gQLqv9f4o';
}

function loadPlayer() { 
  if (typeof(YT) == 'undefined' || typeof(YT.Player) == 'undefined') {

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
      onYouTubePlayer();
    };

  } else {

    onYouTubePlayer();

  }
}

var player;

function onYouTubePlayer() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '490',
    width: '880',
    videoId: getArtistId(),
    playerVars: { controls:1, showinfo: 0, rel: 0, showsearch: 0, iv_load_policy: 3 },
    events: {
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
      'onError': catchError
    }
  });
}

  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      // setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    } else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      location.reload();
    }
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {

    //if(typeof(SONG.getArtistId()) == undefined)
    //{
    //  console.log("undefineeeed"); 
    //} 
    //event.target.playVideo();   
  }
  function catchError(event)
  {
    if(event.data == 100) console.log("De video bestaat niet meer");
  }

  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
```

And a live example :  <del>http://jsbin.com/maweqahuhi/1/</del> http://jsbin.com/nipogicide/2/

**EDIT**

Regarding your commentq i made some changement in the code.
You need to use `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady()` to call the player later. I edited all the previous code.

Comment: Yes, but now you're not putting it in a module. Which is exactly what I need.

Comment: @RW24 from what i saw in your code, you don't need a module, `$(document).ready(function()` is useless

Comment: The document.ready was just to show that I call the function from somewhere.. :)

Comment: When the document is ready you call a function to create the player. Why you want to call a function to create a player when the document is ready ? You can load the player by default. It's not really clear for me.

Comment: I use other API's where I get the playing song of a music station. So I need to make sure the API of youtube waits until I've got that song. That's why I want to call that function later. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @RW24 i made an edit of the code. See at the end for the explanation

Comment: Shouldn't the `else` just load that same function again? `if (YT...) { doSomething(); } else { checkAgain(); }` ?