# How to know when youtube fully loaded?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have chrome-extension content_script that need to add something to youtube video description and comment section.

Problem is that youtube loads async, first you can see template, than video, than description section and comments section.

Is there an event that can be triggered when page fully loaded? Or some other easy solution?

I can think only to one solution - rerun useEffect every second until all the containers could be found.

```
export const App = () => {
  const [postContainer, setPostContainer] = useState<null | HTMLElement>(null)
  const [commentsContainer, setCommentsContainer] = useState<null | HTMLElement>(null)

  useEffect(() => {  
    $('#meta-contents').first().prepend(`<div id='my-post' />`)
    $('#comments').first().prepend(`<div id='my-comment' />`)

    setPostContainer($('#my-post').get(0))
    setCommentsContainer($('#my-comment').get(0))
  }, [])

  if (!postContainer || !commentsContainer) return null

  return (
    <div>
      <Portal target={postContainer}>
        <h1>POST</h1>
      </Portal>
      <Portal target={commentsContainer}>
        <h1>COMMENT</h1>
      </Portal>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Have a look on this answer with a YT api solution in it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60109330/5506730 . It might help.

Comment: @gazdagergo what exactly i need to look at?

Comment: [How to detect page navigation on YouTube and modify HTML before page is rendered?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34100952) - see if there are some events you can use.

Comment: @wOxxOm it's another problem, but thanks, will be helpfull.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508954/2118955

Comment: @hindmost MutationObserver seems what i need.

Comment: @hindmost yep, it is

Comment: @RTW the `videoStatuses` will give you the loaded status in the mentioned example.