# Creating YouTube player results in - Uncaught ReferenceError: YT is not defined error

Tags: javascript, api, google-api, youtube-api

Why am I getting this error? I'm creating a youtube player embed via the YT api but I keep getting an alert that the variable YT is not defined. I can see that the script for the youtube API is getting included, which is supposed to create the variable YT - so why isn't this working?

and My code:

```
    //submit button to call getRequest
    $('#search-term').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var searchTerm = $('#query').val();
        test = getRequest(searchTerm);
        console.log("test=");
        console.log(test);
    });
    function getRequest(searchTerm){
        var params = {
            part:'snippet',
            key: "<removed from code to post>",
            q:searchTerm
          };
        url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search';

        $.getJSON(url, params, function(data){
            var returnedVideos = data.items;

            // Let's loop over the thisVideobers in our array
            for (var i = 0; i < returnedVideos.length; i++) {
                // This is the object (returned by searchResult) we're on...
                var thisVideo = returnedVideos[i];
                var thisVideoURL = thisVideo.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url;
                var thisVideoID = thisVideo.id.videoId;

                // We're creating a DOM element for the object
                var elem = document.createElement('img');
                elem.content = thisVideo;
                elem.setAttribute("id", thisVideoID);
                elem.setAttribute("src", thisVideoURL);
                console.log(elem.id);

                // ... and when we click, load the respective video
                elem.addEventListener('click', (function(clickEvent) {
                    return function() {
                        console.log('clickEvent=');
                        console.log(clickEvent);
                        console.log(clickEvent);
                        var YoutubeVideoID = $(this).attr('id');

                        // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
                        var tag = document.createElement('script');
                        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
                        var scriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                        scriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, scriptTag);
                        onYouTubePlayerAPIReady();
                        // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
                        // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
                        var player;
                        function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
                            player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
                                height : '360',
                                width : '640',
                                videoId : YoutubeVideoID
                            });
                        }
                    };
                })(thisVideo));

                document.body.appendChild(elem);
            }
        });         
    }




</script>
```

Full error

> YoutubeTestPlayer.html:64 Uncaught ReferenceError: YT is not defined
>   at onYouTubePlayerAPIReady
>   (file:///C:/........./YoutubeTestPlayer.html?:64:22) at
>   HTMLImageElement.
>   (file:///C:/.........../YoutubeTestPlayer.html?:59:8)

Comment: could you show us the full error message you are getting?

Comment: YoutubeTestPlayer.html:64 Uncaught ReferenceError: YT is not defined
    at onYouTubePlayerAPIReady (file:///C:/........./YoutubeTestPlayer.html?:64:22)
    at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous> (file:///C:/.........../YoutubeTestPlayer.html?:59:8)

Comment: Try to check this [tutorial](http://www.afxdesign.com/web-design-blog/web-development-tips-tricks/youtube-iframe-api-player-undefined-firefox/), it might help you to fix your code or give you an idea to make YouTube embed work. For more information, check these related SO questions [11003216](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003216) and [28149815](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28149815) to know the possible cause of this error that you receive